# help with form target, it popups in a blank page instead of the div I chose

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have set the target of the "pic_form" to a div (pic_target).
The form (pic_form) and the div (pic_target) are both inside the same iframe (iframe_pic).
Whatever I set the target to of the "pic_form", a new page pops up and there is my php script (imageUpload.php) output... WHY?

Here is my main page code:

```
        <form><iframe name="iframe_pic" src="iframe.html"></iframe></form>
```

Here is my iframe.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function reset_imageform(){
    f = document.getElementById("pic_form");
    f.src=f.src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body><form target="pic_target" name="pic_form" id="pic_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="bincgi/imageUpload.php"><input name="pic_file" type="file" id="pic_file" size="35" onChange="this.form.submit();"></form><div id="pic_target" name="pic_target"></div>
```

and here is some of my php file imageUpload.php:

```
    $display_image="<img src='../temp_images/$newfilename'>";
$display_image.="<br><a style='font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;' href='#' onclick='window.parent.reset_imageform();'>remove picture</a>";
echo $display_image;
```

Thanks

IF you need more of the PHP file, just tell me...

Comment: The target attribute is deprecated in forms. If the form is in the frame already, you don't even need that attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you can't target forms to divs, only to frames and iframes, so you the only thing you can do is put an iframe into that div with name `pic_target`

or that iframe can also be hidden and you can use JS to copy the contents from iframe to this div, you just can't point form to a div

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my comment above. The only thing you should have to do is set the iframe target to `iframe_pic`.